# Custom onclick function as property in Knockout SimpleGrid

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js, template-engine

I'd like to display a value within data as a link, and pass a custom function to it's click event (which will eventually display a modal w/ status history).

I have properties "isLink" (bool) and "onClick" (function), which can look like the following:

```
    { headerText: "ColumnName"
      , rowText: function (item) { return item.Product.ProductID.toString(); }
      , isLink: true
      , onClick: function (item) { alert(item.Product.ProductID.toString()); }
    }
```

In the "ko_simpleGrid_grid" template, I have the following:

```
    ...
    <a data-bind=\"attr: { href: 'javascript:void()' }, click: $data.onClick, text: rowText($parent) \" />
    ...
```

When clicked, the alert is "undefined".  If I put:

```
    ...
    , onClick: function () { alert("test"); }
    ...
```

then the alert displays "test".

So I guess my question is, how do I get access to the data from that function?

**EDIT/UPDATE**

I was able to get it working.  The link to the bind documentation helped.  Here is the working code:

```
    ...
    , onClick: function() { alert(this.Product.ProductID.toString()); }
    ...
```

and in the simpleGrid plugin:

```
    ...
    <a data-bind=\"click: $data.onClick.bind($parent), text: rowText($parent) \" />
    ...
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to effectively attach whatever parameter you want to your function call.

In your example, it should work the following way:

```
<a data-bind=\"click: $data.onClick.bind($data, param1), text: rowText($parent) \" />
```

The first parameter of the bind function is the context within the "`onClick`" function. I chose "data" which means that within "onClick" all properties of $data will be available.

You can add as many parameters as you want.

One last note: I suggest removing the `href` attribute, it is not needed and doesn't accomplish anything here.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I still get "undefined" if I do this, though.  Does the fact that I'm using IE8 (have to, unfortunately) have anything to do with it?

Comment: No problem. I have IE8 at work, and I can assure you that the "bind" works. You may have another problem. If you could set up a jsfiddle with what you have I could help you more.

Comment: To show an example, I need to be able to modify/include the simpleGrid plugin within jsfiddle, which I haven't been able to do....

Comment: Just updated the question.  You pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: Nice! Have fun with Knockout :-)